# Difference between startActivityForResult() and startActivity()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

What is the difference between `startActivityForResult()` and `startActivity()`  ?

When, and for what, should I use each one ?

Comment: Read Before Ask Question.   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: startActivity() simply starts an activity.
startActivityForResult() starts an activity and return the generated result in onActivityResult() method of calling activity

Comment: check this link http://saiful103a.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/android-startactivity-and-startactivityforresult/

Answer (score 43):

### startActivity

Start an activity, like you would start an application: for instance: you have an app with a home-screen and a user-info screen: if you press the user-info button, you start the user-info activity with this.

### startActivityForResult

Start an activity and expect something in return. For instance, on your user-info screen, you can upload a profile picture. You start the gallery-activity with the explicit goal to get a URI back with the preferred picture. You start this activity literaly to obtain a result (the picture. There are some techinical ways to make sure you actually get the result, but they are quite clear in the manual.

Answer (score 30):

**startActivity** will start a new activity and not care when where and how that activity finishes.

evidently

**startActivityForResult** waits for callbacks when the started activity decided to finish

**startActivity()** will start the activity you want to start without worrying about getting any result from new child activity started by startActivity to parent activity.

**startActivityForResult()** starts another activity from your activity and it expect to get some data from newly started child activity  by startAcitvityForResult()  and return that to parent activity.

Check this link - [`Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)