# Sending SongIndex through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a music player. I want to play a selected song from ListView. But when i click on the specific item(song) in listview. I am not getting the item(song) i clicked in second class. The player always selects first song from list and plays the first song. I think that there is problem in code. Please check and correct. Thanks

**Tab1(Sending Class)**

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    int songIndex = position;

    // Starting new intent
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
    in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
    getActivity().setResult(100, in);
    // Closing PlayListView
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(in);
}
```

**NowPlaying(Receiving Class)**

```
 /**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are those 2 classes of different apps? Why don't you pass an extra with the intent? Anyways you are not startingForResult. It's a bit confusing

Comment: How does your onCreate method in NowPlaying.class look like?

Comment: @user6547359 These two classes are of same app. In first class, songs are loaded in listView. When i click on any song, the class which receives songIndex is not playing that song.

Comment: @AkshaySharma probably because your result is never 100 there. Pass it as extra as you do with the index, and start it in the oncreate (or on resume). When you start activity for result you expect that the started activity returns a result, not viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

From the first activity you need to call `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. Don't call `finish()` on this activity after that

And from the activity that is going to return the result you just set the result before finishing using `finish()` the activity don't call `startActivity()` to invoke the old activity.

Do not use class name for the intent constructor in second activity. User default intent constructor

Answer (score 0):

**To pass the position of the song**

**Tab1**

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
    in.putExtra("songIndex", position);
    startActivity(in);
    getActivity().finish();

}
```

**NowPlaying(Receiving Class)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name); //insert here you activity's xml layout
    currentSongIndex = getExtras().getInt("songIndex"); 
 // currentSongIndex now holds an integer value, the position of the song selected from your list. After that you should call your function to play the specific song
}
```

Comment: Add the 100 "result" in the extras if you need it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

See there are two things :

1. If you want to pass it through `Intent` object and want to receive it in another class you need to receive it in `onCreate` like this :

   **In NowPlaying(Receiving Class)**

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       currentSongIndex = getIntent().getStringExtra("songIndex");               
   }
   ```
2. If you want to do it by in `onActivityResult` then your `NowPlaying` activity must have started `Tab1Activity` with `startActivityForResult()`. And no need on starting an activity in `onListItemClick` in `Tab1`

---

**EDIT :**

You need to under stand the difference i guess : [Difference between startActivityForResult() and startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119992/difference-between-startactivityforresult-and-startactivity)