# difference between intent and startActivityForResult in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

Actually I want to know the work of intent and startActivityForResult.Its little confusion on this topic.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119992/difference-between-startactivityforresult-and-startactivity

Answer (score 0):

Intent is a mechanism for communicating between different components of android (i.e. Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, etc.)

Where as startActivity() and startActivityForResult() are used to start another activity.

`startActivity()`-use to start another activity
`startActivityForResult()` - use when you are expecting some result from the activity you want to start.